# Building pyramids of virtual raster not permanent when file is moved

Tags: qgis, raster, vrt, image-pyramids

I have a folder saved under:

C:\QGIS\Active Layers\

In the "Active Layers" folder there our two folders; one called "Geotiffs" and the other "Virtual Raster".

In QGIS 2.18.20 I created a virtual raster with the .tif files contained in the "Geotiffs" folder and saved the virtual raster in my "Virtual Raster" folder. I created pyramids using the internal if possible option which created a .ovr file alongside my .vrt file. Everthing worked as expected.

Now if I move the "Active Layers" folder onto someone else's computer and save it in the exact same file path the pyramids don't work properly causing the virtual raster to disappear when I zoom in so far.

What have I done wrong and is there a way around it?

Comment: Open the .vrt file and check if it has a "relativeToVRT" attribute for the overviews http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html or if an absolute path is used. But I do not understand why virtual raster disappears when you zoom **in**. Overviews are used when you zoom **out**.

Comment: Yes "relativeToVRT" is used in the .vrt file

Comment: How about SourceFilename elements, do the paths look good? Do other users have rights for all the directories?

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that "relativeToVRT" is set "= 0". So does this mean it is absolute?

Comment: Yes, it means absolute. But if you and the other users have identical paths it should not make any difference.

Comment: For some reason the SourceFilename created a different path fro a couple of tiff files. I don't understand why. I re-downloaded the data and ran it again and seemed to work fine